# Drive Api v3 not returning all files from the root folder

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I am using the following code to retrieve all the files from the root folder of my google drive.

```
List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
            Files.List req = null;

            try {
                  req = driveService.files().list();
                  FileList files = req.setQ("'root' in parents and trashed=false").execute();
                  result.addAll(files.getFiles());          
                  req.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
                } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
                req.setPageToken(null);
              }

          //Print out all the files and folder of root Directory  
            for(File f:result)
            {
                System.out.println("recvd data are: "+f.getName());
            }
```

But the issue is that still not all files are being retrieved instead only 14 files are returning from the drive always. Can anybody please guide me where I am going wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The root folder can also be addressed with a special alias named ['root'](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/children/list#parameters), so you can get all files and folders in the root with the following query:

HTTP request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q='root' *in parent
```

Use the alias `root` for the parameter `folderId` to list all files in the root folder. All requests to the Google Drive API must be authorized by an authenticated user. Google Drive uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authenticating a Google account and authorizing access to user data. You can also use [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2).

```
List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
Files.List request = null;

try {
request = mService.files().list();
FileList files = request.setQ("'root' in parents and trashed=false").execute();
result.addAll(files.getItems()); 
request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
} 
catch (IOException e)
{
System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
request.setPageToken(null);
}

//Print out all the files and folder of root Directory 
for(File f:result)
{
System.out.println("recvd data are: "+f.getTitle());
}
```